# How to copy a project to another PC in Pycharm (python)

Tags: python, pycharm, project

Probably a noob question here, but, much as I've searched I still haven't figured this out.

I'm using Pycharm Community to code stuff for doing misc work tasks. To help with calculations, to put stuff in order, etc.

Only problem is, when I'm WFH, coding is on my home PC. When I'm at the office, it's at my office PC.

And I can't figure out how to copy the project from one PC to the other. If I simply copy the project directory, I get all sorts of errors relating to the venv and dependencies. What's worked so far is to create a new project on the other PC, install the required dependencies, and then just copy the .py files from one place to another. But, that's not going to be practical when the code is done and needs to be shared.

Yeah, and despite all that, they gave me an IDE and told me to code :D

Anyone know a fix for this one?

Comment: This is just an environment issue. You also have to copy your environment somehow. I would suggest using a Docker image.

Comment: Your code should be in *version control*. Dependencies can be listed in e.g. a `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt` that lives alongside your code.

Comment: Don't copy your virtual environment to an other machine! Create a new one based on `requierments.txt` file.

Comment: Consider using a some online repository, push your changes when finished, pull after you move. No IDE settings though, and you will have to install and configure independently in both places.

Comment: Sounds like a good starting point! I'll give the Docker and requirements.txt methods a read...